# How to resolve gradle dependency conflicts when 2 libraries using different version of some other library

Tags: android, gradle, koin

One library is using `org.koin:koin-android:2.1.6` and other is using `org.koin:koin-android:1.0.2`.

Now if I use both of these libraries together, I get `classDefNotFound`.

If i force "2.1.6", second library starts crashing, and if i use "1.0.2" first starts crashing.

```
 implementation('library') {
        exclude group: 'org.koin', module: 'koin-android'
    }
```

So exclude, force are not possible, as "koin" has added some new classes in their latest version.

What should be the solution in this case. Is it possible to keep different version of libraries, or define some kind of alias, so both libraries use their respective version without any issue.

Comment: I've facing same issue here. In my case my project uses most recent Koin version. But has a dependency which use more outdated version of Koin.